# Is there a way to display a unique countdown timer in table rows with time stored in the database using Asp.net Core MVC?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, razor, datatable, countdowntimer

I am building a cart booking system. Since bookings can be from 1 hour to 6 hours, there must be a countdown timer using the time stored in the database. All booked carts are displayed in a table, with a countdown timer for each cart stored in the database.

```
 <table id="example" class="table table-striped  dt-responsive nowrap" width="100%" 
  cellspacing="0">
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
      <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CartNumber)</th>
      <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CartType)</th>
      <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Status)</th>              
      <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CustomerID)</th>
      <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Duration)</th>
      <th>Remaining Time</th>
      <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => 
   model.ImageContent)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
     { 
     <tr>
       <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => 
  item.CartNumber)</td>
       <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => 
 item.CartType)</td>
       <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)</td>
       <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => 
 item.CustomerID)</td>
       <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => 
 item.Duration)</td>
       <td><p class="demo@(item.ID)"></p></td>
       <td><img height="50" width="70" 
src='@Url.Action( "BookedCarts", "File", new { id = item.ID })' /> </td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>



                                                <script>
    // Set the date we're counting down to
    var countDownDate = new Date('@item.DurationCountdown').getTime();

    // Update the count down every 1 second
    var x = setInterval(function() {

      // Get today's date and time
      var now = new Date().getTime();

      // Find the distance between now and the count down date
      var distance = countDownDate - now;

      // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
      var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 
 60));
      var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

      // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
        //document.getElementsByClassName('demo')[0].innerHTML = hours + "h "
        //    + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

        [... document.getElementsByClassName("demo@(item.ID)")].forEach(e => 
e.innerHTML =  hours + "h "
            + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ");

      // If the count down is over, write some text
      if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
          document.getElementsByClassName("demo")[0].innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
      }
    }, 1000);



                                                </script>
```

My challenge is that only one timer is displayed for all carts; I want all the booked carts to display unique countdown timers based on the hours booked. Below is my code. I am using JavaScript Countdown Timer and ASP.NET Core MVC with Razor Pages, and I will greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, I think we don't need to think about how to save the remain time in our database. The records are useless when the orders were finished, they should be deleted to save the resource.

Countdown based on creating records, I think this fits the countdown you want to be unique.

As you know, when you created a new record and it will have the createTime. And I don't know what the bookings time value, so I assume it is 2 hours, you can accord to your business to change it. Then I can accord to the createTime to get the remain seconds like below.

[image]

Then we don't need to store the remain time in our database, every time when we refresh the page, it will returns the exact time with the entity data.

I also find a good countdown sample for you. You can check the source code and use it in your page. We just need to replace the value of data.

[image]

[image]

**Source Code:**

```js
/** 
 * Plugin
 * @author Tungse
 * @param dayTag           show day html
 * @param hourTag          show hour html
 * @param minTag           show minutes html
 * @param secTag           show second html
 * @param dayClass         bind day tag ClassName
 * @param hourClass        bind hours tag ClassName
 * @param minClass         bind minutes tag ClassName
 * @param secClass         bind seconds tag ClassName
 * @param isDefault        whether use default tagTemp
 * @param showTemp         show template 0：(day hour min sec) 1：(hour min sec)
 * @param backfun          finish callback
 */
(function ($) {
      $.fn.countdownsync = function (tagTemp, backfun) {
        var data = "";
        var _DOM = null;
        var _defaultTag = _TempTag = {
            dayTag: "<li class='countdownday'></li><li class='split'>day</li>",
            hourTag: "<li class='countdownhour'></li><li class='split'>:</li>",
            minTag: "<li class='countdownmin'></li><li class='split'>:</li>",
            secTag: "<li class='countdownsec'></li><li class='split'>:</li>",
            dayClass: ".countdownday",
            hourClass: ".countdownhour",
            minClass: ".countdownmin",
            secClass: ".countdownsec",
            isDefault: false,
            showTemp:0
        };
        var _temp = $.extend(_TempTag, tagTemp);
        var TIMER;
        createdom = function (dom) {
            _DOM = dom;
            data = Math.round($(dom).attr("data"));
            var htmlstr = (_temp.showTemp == 0 ? _temp.dayTag : "") + _temp.hourTag + _temp.minTag + _temp.secTag;
            if (_temp.isDefault) {
                htmlstr = (_temp.showTemp == 0 ? _defaultTag.dayTag : "") + _defaultTag.hourTag + _defaultTag.minTag + _defaultTag.secTag;
                htmlstr = "<ul class='countdown'>" + htmlstr + "</ul>";
                $("head").append("<style type='text/css'>.countdown {list-style:none;}.countdown li{float:left;background:#000;color:#fff;border-radius:50%;padding:10px;font-size:14px; font-weight:bold;margin:10px;}.countdown li.split{background:none;margin:10px 0;padding:10px 0;color:#000000;}</style>");
            }
            $(_DOM).html(htmlstr);
            reflash();
        };
        reflash = function () {
            var range = data,
                        secday = 86400, sechour = 3600,
                        days = parseInt(range / secday),
                        hours = _temp.showTemp == 0 ? parseInt((range % secday) / sechour) : parseInt(range / sechour),
                        min = parseInt(((range % secday) % sechour) / 60),
                        sec = ((range % secday) % sechour) % 60;
            data--;
            if (range < 0) {
                window.clearInterval(TIMER); //clear timer
            } else {
                $(_DOM).find(_temp.dayClass).html(nol(days));
                $(_DOM).find(_temp.hourClass).html(nol(hours));
                $(_DOM).find(_temp.minClass).html(nol(min));
                $(_DOM).find(_temp.secClass).html(nol(sec));
            }
            if ((range - 1) == 0) {
                undefined == backfun ? function () { } : backfun();
            }
        };
        TIMER = setInterval(reflash, 1000);
        nol = function (h) {
            return h > 9 ? h : '0' + h;
        };
        return this.each(function () {
            var $box = $(this);
            createdom($box);
        });
    };
   
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<title>countdown plugin</title>
<style>
    h3{margin-top: 30px}    
    .ys1{
        color: #009AC1;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .ys2{
    color: #2FAB11;
    font-weight: bold;
    }
    .ys3{
    color: #C16000;
    font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
     <h3>60s countdown</h3>
     <p>data="60" </p>
    <div class="container timeBar ys1" data="60" ></div>
    
    <h3>600s countdown</h3>
    <p>data="600" </p>
    <div class="container timeBar ys2" data="600" ></div>
    
    <h3>160000s countdown</h3>
    <p>data="160000" </p>
    <div class="container timeBar ys3" data="160000" ></div>
</div>

<script src="https://www.jq22.com/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="countdown.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $(".timeBar").each(function () {
            $(this).countdownsync({
                dayTag: "",
                hourTag: "<label class='tt hh dib vam'>00</label><span> hours </span>",
                minTag: "<label class='tt mm dib vam'>00</label><span> minutes </span>",
                secTag: "<label class='tt ss dib vam'>00</label><span> seconds </span>",
                dayClass: ".dd",
                hourClass: ".hh",
                minClass: ".mm",
                secClass: ".ss",
                isDefault: false,
                showTemp:1

            }, function () {
                location.reload();
            });
        });
    });
    
</script>

</body>
</html>
```